# How to get equal spacing between <li>s styled with float:left; in a responsive-width div

Tags: css, responsive-design

jsfiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/Sapphireblue/781rrymp/39/ & code at bottom

I have four nav elements, each text in LIs side-by-side via float:left, in a UL, in a DIV, in a NAV, in a DIV whose width is a percentage of its parent element(s). (I am using a responsive grid layout and these LIs are populated by a WordPress menu, so there may well be a more efficient way to achieve this with less overhead, but that efficiency is not part of the spec for this project.)

What I want to do is to keep the left edge of the left-most LI at the left edge of all its parents; the right edge of the right-most LI at the right edge of all its parents; and have the other two LIs evenly spaced between the outer two. So kind of like a fully justified line of text.

Turns out, this is hard. Between the percentage-width div, which means that any margin I specify for the LIs is unsuitable as soon as you resize, and the fact that the text items in the LIs are of different widths so, and etc etc, I can't get the last LI flush right in a way that stays there for any resize (not even setting LI last-child margin-right to 0}.

I've played with various units for my LIs and none is right. I tried media queries for small adjustments to font sizes on the LIs as you resize the browser window and that parent div shrinks, which helps, but unless I set a breakpoint every 5 pixels, this isn't workable as a solution. If I work out margins that are ~close~ to what I want and then just set float:right on the last-child LI, it looks dumb if you resize the window down to where that last LI appears on its own line.

Gotta be a way to do this. And sorry if the question has been asked; I did browse but didn't find anything quite a match.

(Note: I'm not worried about widths so small the LIs wrap onto 2 lines, I just don't want there to be a gap of whitespace to the right of the UL, at any width where the UL can be contained on the one line.)

```
#myDiv {
    width:50%;
    margin:0;
    border:1px solid red;
    overflow:auto;
}
#myDiv ul {
    padding:0;
    margin:0 0 0 0;
    height:auto;
}
#myDiv li {
    list-style-type: none;
    float:left;
    background-color:yellow;
    margin-right:20px; /* this value is only good for one
                          specific viewport width: ugggh */
}
#myDiv li:last-child {
    margin-right:0px;
}



<div id="myDiv">
    <nav>
        <div>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="foo">Item 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="foo">Item Two</a></li>
                <li><a href="foo">#3</a></li>
                <li><a href="foo">Longer Item Four</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: Accepted what seemed like the best answer (which was the one that didn't involve tables!) but wanted to say I didn't get a chance to really put that answer though its paces. The client I was working for decided in January that they didn't want to continue with the project and didn't want to pay me for my work... legally-binding contract be damned. Ah, the freelance life! Anyway, so the answer's untested but seems solid... I appreciate the effort and sorry for the delay in acceptance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, this sounds like it would be difficult to achieve and unreliable, especially given that the nav text can be edited through a CMS.

In this situation I'd be inclined to handle it a little differently, using display: inline-block on the list items.

```
#myDiv li {
    list-style-type: none;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color:yellow;
    margin: 0 2px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/781rrymp/40/

Answer (score 0):

How about using TABLE instead of UL. The code would be:

```
<style type="text/css">
#myDiv {
    width:50%;
    margin:0;
    border:1px solid red;
    overflow:auto;
}
#myDiv table {
    padding:0;
    margin:0 0 0 0;
    height:auto;
    width: 100%;

}
#myDiv td {
    width: 25%;
    background-color: yellow;
    border-right: 20px solid white;
}
#myDiv td:last-child {
    border-right: 0px;
}
</style>

<div id="myDiv">
    <nav>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td><a href="foo">Item 1</a></td>
                <td><a href="foo">Item Two</a></td>
                <td><a href="foo">#3</a></td>
                <td><a href="foo">Longer Item Four</a></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </nav>
</div>
```